# How to play multiple videos from one file?

Tags: c++, qt, video-player, qmediaplayer

I am working on Media Player Software. My application so far can play, pause and fast forward etc, a video.

I can currently play/load one video using:

```
void Dialog::on_loadedButton_clicked(){
     player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("F:/TestVideo/20141208/N01000713.mp4"));
}
```

- My folder (20141208) is the date
- `N01000713.mp4` is the file name of my footage generated by my camera.
- N01 is channel 1
- 00:07:13 is my HH:MM:ss when the video starts
- It ends after 10 minutes, that is N01001713.mp4.

I have 144 videos in my 20141208 folder to make up 24 hours worth of footage since one video plays for 10 minutes.

Now I want to generalize for a folder that contains a date e.g. 20141208, that has 144 videos and the file name is N01(HH:MM:SS).mp4 to be able to play all the 144 videos.

I do not want to setMedia for this 144 videos to be fixed because I want to be able to play videos for different dates, e.g. date 20141208, 20141209 folders etc.

How can I do that

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Do you want to play all videos one after another so you simply want a list of files? Or do you want to play multiple videos at the same time? Please [read this carefully](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then **edit** your question accordingly so it is clear what you are asking us (Hint: most questions contain a question mark)

Comment: So go through all the files in that folder, check for valid `.mp4` files and add them to a `QMediaPlaylist`. What is the problem?